# How to fix login keyring?

Tags: login

I install Opera on a Linux machine. However, every time I open Opera, I got this message:
"Authentication required. The login keyring did not get unlocked when you logged into your computer."
I looked for the solutions on the Internet but still don't work in my case. Do you know how to fix this?

I found this document related to the issue but it is quite complicated to know how to apply. Thank you in advance!

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GNOME/Keyring#Disable_keyring_daemon_components

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not use keyring at all - you can safely remove the default key file.

Go to `~/.local/share/keyrings` There would be a file `login.keyring`. Rename it or delete.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much.

Comment: Today, I don't know why the error message appears again. I have 4 files in ~/.local/share/keyrings 
default  Default_keyring  login.keyring.rename  user.keystore

Comment: @chris The removal of default file disables attempts to use keyring with empty set of keys, by any app which checks existence of keyring's DB. But it does not disable keyring itself. Each time some app decides it wants to create a key - the keyring creates a DB for them, you cancel new password creation - empty DB remains. The more permanent solution - `sudo apt remove gnome-keyring`, but it has its own set of problems with apps who expect the keyring usage at some point (including inet browsers).